# Mono Tesseract 3 ddlmap can't map liblept172.so

Tags: mono, tesseract

I want to use tesseract 3 nuget package with mono. I have a dll not found error at runtime : System.DllNotFoundException : Failed to find library liblept172.so for platform x64.
I tried to add a config file in the same folder of dll , and in et/mono/config too.

```
<dllmap dll="liblept172.dll" target="/usr/lib/liblept.so"/>
```

I tried rename dll in liblept.dll.
I added /usr/lib to ldconfig and i linked liblept172.so to liblept.so with no result. Is someone using tesseract 3 with mono (archlinux) ?

```
using System;
using Tesseract;
using System.Drawing;
namespace tesstessarct
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            using (TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine (@"/usr/share/tessdata", "fra", EngineMode.TesseractOnly, "config")) 

            {
                engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
                var page = engine.Process (new Bitmap("/test.jpg"));
                Console.Write (page.GetText ());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21041974. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a quick reply, I will immediately this comment here.

Answer (score 0):

The Tesseract Nuget :

```
<package id="Tesseract" version="3.0.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Is **only** the .Net/Mono wrapper. You will **also need** the language files and the native shared libraries built for ArchLinux

Build from Source: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Install from package: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/tesseract/

Comment: i also installed tesseract library and i can compile tesseratc (g++ testTEss.cpp -o tesstest -llept -ltesseract) and i installed  tessdata training for my language.

Comment: Look at `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in order to set the search path so `dlopen` can find the `liblept172.so` library:   http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#linux-shared-library-search-path

Comment: Is `liblept.so` a symlink to `liblept172.so`?

Comment: no, mono search for liblept172.so, i made a link ln -s liblept.so liblept172.so in /usr/lib with no success